# How to filter HTML table by date using DATETIMEPICKER?

Tags: jquery, filter, html-table

Here is my table:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" name="myInputSearches" placeholder="Week..." style="margin-top:4px">
<label class="noResults" align="right" style="display:none; color:red"><b><i>No Match Found</i></b></label>

....

<tbody id="myTable">
    {% for event in eventList %}
      <tr>
        <td><div style="width:100px">{{ event.week|date:"d-m-Y" }}</div></td>
        <td><div style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase">{{ event.name }}</div></td>
        <td><div id="day0" style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase">{{ event.sunday }}</div></td>
        <td><div id="day1" style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase">{{ event.monday }}</div></td>
        <td><div id="day2" style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase">{{ event.tuesday }}</div></td>
        <td><div id="day3" style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase">{{ event.wednesday }}</div></td>
        <td><div id="day4" style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase">{{ event.thursday }}</div></td>
        <td><div id="day5" style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase">{{ event.friday }}</div></td>
        <td><div id="day6" style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase">{{ event.saturday }}</div></td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
```

This is my current jQuery to filter the table:

```
<script> //No Results message
  $(document).ready(function () {
    (function ($) {
      $("#myInput").keyup(function () {
        var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), "i");
        $("#myTable tr").hide();
        $("#myTable tr").filter(function () {
          return rex.test($(this).text());
        }).show();
        $(".noResults").hide();
        if($("#myTable tr:visible").length == 0) {
          $(".noResults").show();
        }
      })
    }(jQuery));
  });
```

I am currently able to filter when I type in my query. I would like to use datetimepicker to select a date which then filters the table.

This is how I have implemented datetimepicker for "myInput":

```
$(function () {
  $('#myInput').datetimepicker({
    format:'DD-MM-YYYY',
  });

  $('#myInput').on('dp.change', function (e) {
    var value = $("#myInput").val();
    var firstDate = moment(value, "DD/MM/YYYY").day(0).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    $("#myInput").val(firstDate);
  });
});
```

But whenever I select a date, the table does not filter. I think it's due to the "keyUp" function, but I am not sure what to change it to.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `keyup` with `change`?

Comment: @Tanmay yes i have tried that but still does not work

Comment: Ok. Then trigger `change` event programmatically inside `dp.change`. Ie.  `$("#myInput").val(firstDate).change();`

Comment: @Tanmay added change() and replaced keyup with change, still not working :(

Comment: Which plugin you are using for datetimepicker?

Comment: <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

Comment: Please see the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you need to trigger desired Event programmatically from `dp.change`.

OR

Place the your code inside dateimepicker's `dp.change` event handler.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {   
   
        $('#myInput').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
        });

        $('#myInput').on('dp.change', function (e) {
         var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), "i");
        $("#myTable tr").hide();
        $("#myTable tr").filter(function () {
            return rex.test($(this).text());
        }).show();
        $(".noResults").hide();
        if ($("#myTable tr:visible").length == 0) {
            $(".noResults").show();
        }
        });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


 <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group" style="position:relative">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    
                    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myInputSearches" class="form-control"  >
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        

<label class="noResults" align="right" style="display:none; color:red"><b><i>No Match Found</i></b></label>


<table>
<tbody id="myTable">
   
      <tr>
        <td><div style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase">name </div></td>
        <td><div id="day0" style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase">23-01-2019 </div></td>
        <td><div id="day1" style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase">monday</div></td>
        <td><div id="day2" style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase"> tuesday </div></td>
        <td><div id="day3" style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase">wednesday </div></td>
        <td><div id="day4" style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase">thursday</div></td>
        <td><div id="day5" style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase">friday </div></td>
        <td><div id="day6" style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase"> saturday</div></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase">name </div></td>
        <td><div id="day0" style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase">30-01-2019 </div></td>
        <td><div id="day1" style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase">monday</div></td>
        <td><div id="day2" style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase"> tuesday </div></td>
        <td><div id="day3" style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase">wednesday </div></td>
        <td><div id="day4" style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase">thursday</div></td>
        <td><div id="day5" style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase">friday </div></td>
        <td><div id="day6" style="width:200px; text-transform: uppercase"> saturday</div></td>
      </tr>
   
  </tbody>
  <table>
```